# ArgumentError: assertion message must be String or Proc using assert_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, testunit

I'm writing a controller test for a rails 3.1 app using testunit 2.4.0.

I want to assert that a certain heading does not appear on the page.

I'm using assert_select like this:

```
assert_select 'h1', {:text => /Key Dates/, :count => 0}
```

and getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError: assertion message must be String or Proc: <</Key Dates/>
expected but was <"Planner Maternity leave">.>(<Test::Unit::Assertions::AssertionMessage>)
```

I've tracked this down to the fact that `assert_select` calls `build_message` which creates an instance of `AssertionMessage` and passes it through to test-unit's `assert`. However in version 2.2 of testunit (Feb 2011) checks were added which check the type of the message passed in. These checks trigger the `ArgumentError` seen above.

I'm not sure whether the mistake lies with test-unit being over-strict or assert_select passing the wrong object type.

Can you advise how best to follow this up? Any work-arounds?

Comment: Is the problem that the value in `:text` is supposed to be a string, and not a pattern?

Comment: Hi, no it's quite acceptable for :text to be a Regexp

Answer (score 0):

So, the [assert_select documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select) shows the following example, passing a block in:

```
assert_select "ol" do |elements|
  elements.each do |element|
    assert_select element, "li", 4
  end
end
```

So what if you did something like...

```
assert_select 'h1' do |elements|
  elements.length == 0 ? fail
  elements.each do |element|
    element.text ~= /Key Dates/ ? fail
  end
end
```

Which basically fails if it finds the pattern OR if the number of `h1` elements is zero. Obviously you would change the conditions to match what it is you're trying to test for, but does that get you any closer to what you need?

Answer (score 0):

*If you cannot upgrade* to a bug-free version, you can just pass a third argument (the message), so you do not force the message be built:

`assert_select 'h1', {:text => /Key Dates/, :count => 0}, "Unexpected Key Dates found."`